# How to Change text color on AppCompatSpinner in Toolbar?

Tags: android, spinner, toolbar, android-appcompat

I have recently updated to API 24 and now I am having a problem with the text color on my AppCompatSpinner inside the Toolbar.

Here is what I am talking about, notice how "Pils" at the very top is black. Pre API 24 this was white. (Also, running this APP on a device which is not on API 24 the text shows up white as it should.)

[image]

Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.baviloworks.braumeister'
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 100
        versionName '1.0.0'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.3'
}
```

Here is my style.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/DarkBlue</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/Green</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="customTabText" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
        <item name="android:textSize">13sp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

and here is the XML if my Toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/Toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/Blue"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
        android:id="@+id/Recipe_Selection_Spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:popupBackground="@drawable/spinner_rounded_corners"
        android:minWidth="175dp"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

It would be great if someone could point me in the right direction!

Thanks :)

I have now tried this:

```
cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.custom_spinner, dbData, recipeNames, recipeTo, 0);
cursorAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
recipeLoadSelection.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
```

and this is the custom spinner:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"        
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

But now the text won't show up at all

Answer (score 9, accepted):

a) Whatever you do do not use application context to inflate views. If you're using `SimpleCursorAdapter` it uses the context from constructor to inflate views internally.

b) Use the themed context of your toolbar for widgets inside it. Your toolbar overrides `android:theme` attribute. You'll want to use this context to inflate any views within that toolbar.

Meaning instead of `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` write `getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext()` and it will just work. This is the correct approach, it does not hardcode text color.

Answer (score 0):

Create custom_spinner.xml:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

Set custom spinner text using adapter

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.spinner_array, R.layout.custom_spinner);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I tried something like this, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: do this :
 ArrayAdapter<String> spnUser_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Admin_morabi_transActivity.this,R.layout.spinner_item, usersString);
            spnUser_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            sp.setAdapter(spnUser_adapter);

Answer (score -2):

I got it working like this:

create a new custom_spinner.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="@style/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textAlignment="inherit"/>
```

create a new spinner style:

```
<style name="spinnerItemStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/White</item>
</style>
```